# problem getting the friends birthday with facebook api

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

here is the code , that supposed to retreive the birthday of my friends corresponding to today .

```
$friends = $facebook->api('me/friends');
$uids = "";

foreach($friends as $f) {
  $uids .= "uid=$f OR ";
}

$query_uids = substr($uids,0,strlen($query_uids)-4);
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
$current_date = date("m/d");
echo "<br />searching : $current_date<br />";

$data = $facebook->api(array('method'=>'fql.query','req_perms' => 'friends_birthday','query'=>"SELECT name, uid FROM user WHERE ( ($query_uids) AND strpos(birthday_date,'$current_date') >= 0 )") );

if(count($data) > 0) {
  foreach($data as $d) {
    print_r($d);
  }
} else {
 echo "<br />No Birthdays Today<br />";
 }
```

in my page i have another script to retrive user friends too above this one and its working properly , 
the result shown with this snippet issearching and WHITE SPACE !!!!

please help
thanks

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm also struggling with this.

Answer (score 0):

When you mean getting friends' birthdays corresponding to today - I'm assuming you want to find if any of your friends birthday is today or not.

1) First thing, you have to get today's date:

```
$today = date('m\/d');
```

2) Second using this date, we will run a query to select all your friends whose birthday is today

```
$data = $facebook->api(array(
    'method'    =>'fql.query',
    'req_perms' => 'friends_birthday',
    'query'     => "select uid,name,birthday_date from user where uid in (select uid2 from friend where uid1=me()) and strpos(birthday_date,$today)>=0 ") );
```

3) Next you check the size of the data set, if it's ZERO - there are no birthdays today, else you loop through the dataset and print the friends name whose birthday is today.

```
if(count($data)==0)
{
   echo 'No Friends Birthdays today';
}
else
{
    echo 'Friends whose birthday is today';
    foreach($data as $today_bday) {
        echo $today_bday['name'];
    }
}
```

If this is not what you are looking for - let me know.

Comment: i copied exactly the code you wrote me , result showed me No Friends Birthdays today even if i have a friend 's birthday !!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Thats pretty weird - It works well for me - Lets try to debug it. Can you do a `print_r($data)` and tell me some sample values you are seeing for the birthday field or are you seeing all null values there. If not give me some example data from the birthday field - Thanks

Comment: Am also getting an empty string/array

Comment: Gublooo, your query is absolutely fine, the problem is with the PHP variable that you are using inside the query. You just forgot to put the PHP variable **inside the quotes**. #Incorrect: strpos(birthday_date,$today) #Correct: strpos(birthday_date,'$today')